# Load Zend_Test_DbAdapter from Zend_Db::factory()

Tags: php, zend-framework, testing, zend-db

How can I obtain and instance of the Zend Framework [Test DbAdapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.phpunit.db.html#zend.test.phpunit.db.adapter) using the [Zend_Db::factory()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.connecting.factory)?

I have the following code but the Factory stamps on my adapter case and breaks the file path. It seems a little ironic their test adapter can't be loaded by their own Factory. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$config = new Zend_Config(
    array(
        'database' => array(
            'adapter' => 'DbAdapter',
            'params' => array(
                'adapterNamespace' => 'Zend_Test',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'mydb',
                'username' => 'not',
                'password' => 'needed'
            )
        )
    )
);

$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);
```

I get the following error:

```
Zend_Loader::include_once(Zend/Test/Dbadapter.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

**Updated**

The code above is a direct copy and paste, the adapter parameter case is correct: 'DbAdapter'. This matches the file case Zend_Test_DbAdapter.

I changed my code to manually instantiate `Zend_Test_DbAdapter` and it autoloads without issue.

```
$db = new Zend_Test_DbAdapter;
print_r(get_class($db));
```

Output:

```
Zend_Test_DbAdapter
```

I still believe the `Zend_Db::factory()` method is nerfing my adapter character case, upper casing the first character, lower casing the rest.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. As Zend's adapters employ lazy connections, for the purpose of testing I was able to use the `pdo_mysql` adapter and assert an instance of `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` was returned from my factory method. This was sufficient for my needs but as far as I can see you can't obtain an instance of `Zend_Test_DbAdapter` via `Zend_Db::factory()`

Answer (score 0):

Check Typo mistake

```
if not 'adapter' => 'Dbadapter', to 'adapter' => 'DbAdapter',

Zend/Test/Dbadapter.php does not exits
Zend/Test/DbAdapter.php exits in library
```

OR

File is Missing

You have to add zend lib in includePath or if its a zend project add zend files into library

/application
/library
 add Zend files (download from http://framework.zend.com/download)

Comment: It's not a typo as I've copied and pasted the code here, you can see the case for adapter is correct in my code. I've updated my question to confirm it's not the latter either (and tested it).